# Change log rollback not restricted to a single contact

Tags: contacts, import

Not so much a question as a development request...

We manually add/edit records but also do a lot of importing into Civi. 
When some errors were found on a particular contact record we used the 'revert these changes' button in the change log expecting it to revert only the update to the single specific contact record.

Unfortunately because the changes were as the result of an import into civi for approximately 650 contacts it rolled back all changes across all 650 records.

Because we could not unpick which specific import it was (there were a number of imports against these 650) we then had to delete all 650 contacts and re-import from scratch.

Not sure where to put the request for future development, but it would be great to be able to choose between a revert against a single record versus the full import set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds frustrating. Thanks for sharing your experience. Feature requests should be made in [CiviCRM's issue tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org).

Comment: And if you do create an issue in JIRA, please post the issue number -- perhaps as a comment to your original question -- so that folks who land on this page as a result of a search might be led to more information. Thanks!